# Ionic, Node Sass does not yet support your current environment

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, ionic3

I switched my OS from windows to Mac, after copying my previous app from windows to Mac while serving my app it’s generating an error:

```
app-scripts] /Volumes/D Drive/Work/Trisquard/carExpense/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13
[app-scripts]       throw new Error(errors.unsupportedEnvironment());
[app-scripts]       ^
[app-scripts] Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 64-bit with Unsupported runtime (72)
[app-scripts] For more information on which environments are supported please see:
[app-scripts] https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.9.0
[app-scripts]     at module.exports (/Volumes/D Drive/Work/Trisquard/carExpense/node_modules/node-sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
[app-scripts]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/D Drive/Work/Trisquard/carExpense/node_modules/node-sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
[app-scripts]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)
[app-scripts]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:947:10)
[app-scripts]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:32)
[app-scripts]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:703:12)
[app-scripts]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:830:19)
[app-scripts]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:68:18)
[app-scripts]     at Object.<anonymous> (/Volumes/D Drive/Work/Trisquard/carExpense/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/core/bundle-components.js:6:16)
[app-scripts]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:936:30)

[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

    The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

My Mac Node.js version (12.9.1) my windows node.js version(8.9.1).
Can anyone tell me how to fix this.

Have already added node version 8.9.1 in Mac but its giving error:

```
ERR: Your Node.js version is v8.9.1. Please update to the latest Node LTS version.
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy the node_modules folder are have you re install as `npm install` after removed it ?

Comment: First i cloned it from github but after having same error tried copying node_modules folder but got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running `npm rebuild node-sass` ?

Comment: Yup, no success.

Comment: I just created new project and copied the app files and it’s working, but i don’t think it’s the proper way.